# Symfony/Doctrine entity mapping configuration

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, bundle, symfony4

I'm studying about creating custom bundles in Symfony 4.1. I have a simple bundle working with a simple controller and a route /hello. I want to create some Doctrine Entities to be used by the external app that includes my bundle. How can I do this configuration and entities mapping? Following my current folder structure:

```
- custom-hello-bundle
    - Controller
        HelloController.php
    - DependencyInjection
        Configuration.php
        CustomHelloExtension.php
    - Resources
        - config
            routes.xml
            services.xml
    - Tests
    composer.json
    CustomHelloBundle.php
    phpunit.xml.dist
```

I know that I have to create an Entity folder, and add an entity called Hello.php (for example). But how do I configure the Doctrine to mapping this entity inside this custom bundle?

Answer (score 0):

You are interested in this part of manual - [Custom mapping entities in bundle](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/doctrine.html#custom-mapping-entities-in-a-bundle) specifically this part.

```
doctrine:
    # ...
    orm:
        # ...
        auto_mapping: true
        mappings:
            # ...
            AppBundle:
                type: xml
                dir: SomeResources/config/doctrine
```